# could logical negation have been implemented as bitwise negation in legacy compilers?

Tags: c

I just found legacy code which tests a flag like this:

```
if( some_state & SOME_FLAG )
```

So far, so good!
But further in code, I see an improper negation

```
if( ! some_state & SOME_FLAG )
```

My understanding is that it is interpreted as `(! some_state) & SOME_FLAG` which is probably a bug, and gcc logically barks with `-Wlogical-not-parentheses`...

Though it could eventually have worked in the past if ever `!some_state` was implemented as `~some_state` by some legacy compiler. Does anyone know if it was possibly the case?

**EDIT**

`sme_state` is declared as int (presumably 32 bits, 2 complement  on target achitecture).
`SOME_FLAG` is a constant set to a single bit 0x00040000, so `SOME_FLAG & 1 == 0`

Comment: Every downvote deserves an explanation or guidance, please take care to enlighten me

Comment: Are you sure the code worked as expected? Maybe the bug does not have any effect for the user?

Comment: This is exactly my question: did this ever work? Since the logical not operation will answer either 0 or 1 nowadays, and that SOME_FLAG is something like 0x4, i'm sure that the `if( ! some_state & SOME_FLAG )` is always false and can be completely eliminated by nowadays compiler.

Comment: @Bodo oh, you mean that code inside the if would have no effect? I don't think so, but that is a possibility to be analyzed...

Comment: I've seen similar code on occasion in the code base I work on.  It's been a bug, every time.  I'd be very inclined to assume it is a bug for your code too.

Comment: Curious: What type is `some_state` and was the platform 16 or 32-bit `int`?

Comment: @aka.nice From time to time I find bugs and ask myself how could it have worked with this bug. Depending on the complexity of the software the user might not notice a bug, maybe because it's effect is only visible in rare cases or maybe because other code is working around the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical negation and bitwise negation have never been equivalent.  No conforming compiler could have implemented one as the other. For example, the bitwise negation of 1 is not 0, so `~1 != !1`.

It is true that the expression `! some_state & SOME_FLAG` is equivalent to `(! some_state) & SOME_FLAG` because logical negation has higher precedence than bitwise and.  That is indeed *suspicious*, but the original code is not necessarily in error.  In any case, it is more likely that the program is buggy in this regard than that any C implementation evaluated the original expression differently than the current standard requires, even prior to standardization.

Since the expressions `(! some_state) & SOME_FLAG` and `!(some_state & SOME_FLAG)` will sometimes evaluate to the same value -- especially if `SOME_FLAG` happens to expand to `1` -- it is also possible that even though they are inequivalent, their differences do not manifest during actual execution of the program.

Comment: This counter example is the simplest that I saw in the answers, and i now understand that my speculation was stupid. Sometimes I don't want to believe the bugs that I see, despite all the evidences.

Answer (score 3):

While there was no standard before 1989, and thus compilers could do things as they wished, no compiler to my knowledge has ever done this; changing the meaning of operators wouldn't be a smart call if you want people to use your compiler.

There's very little reason to write an expression like `(!foo & FLAG_BAR)`; the result is just `!foo` if `FLAG_BAR` is odd or always zero if it is even. What you've found is almost certainly just a bug.

Answer (score 3):

It would not be possible for a legacy compiler to implement `!` as bitwise negation, because such approach would produce incorrect results in situations when the value being negated is outside the {0, 0xFF...FF} set.

Standard requires the result of `!x` to produce zero for any non-zero value of `x`. Hence, applying `!` to, say, 1 would yield 0xFF..FFFE, which is non-zero.

The only situation when the legacy code would have worked as intended is when `SOME_FLAG` is set to `1`.

Comment: Though this is true of C, fun fact, in early versions of VB Booleans were 16 bit integers where false was 0 and true was 0xffff, so bitwise negation worked as you'd expect.

Comment: I have a vague memory of some C compiler implementing true as 0xffffffff too in the 80's, it was before ANSI. But maybe my memory is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the most interesting (and least obvious) part: gcc logically barks with `-Wlogical-not-parentheses`. What does this mean?

C has two different operators that have similar looking characters (but different behaviour and intended for very different purposes) - the `&` which is a bitwise AND, and `&&` which is a boolean AND. Unfortunately this led to typos, in the same way that typing `=` when you meant `==` can cause problems, so some compilers (GCC) decided to warn people about "`&` without parenthesis used as a condition" (even though it's perfectly legal) to reduce the risk of typos.

Now...

You're showing code that uses `&` (and not showing code that uses `&&`). This implies that `some_state` is not a boolean and is number. More specifically it implies that each bit in `some_state` may be completely independent and unrelated.

For an example of this, let's pretend that we're implementing a Pacman game and need a nice compact way to store the map for each level. We decide that each tile in the map might be a wall or not, might be a collected dot or not, might be power pill or not, and might be a cherry or not. Someone suggests that this can be an array of bytes, like this (assuming the map is 30 tiles wide and 20 tiles high):

```
#define IS_WALL         0x01
#define HAS_DOT         0x02
#define HAS_POWER_PILL  0x04
#define HAS_CHERRY      0x08

uint8_t level1_map[20][30] = { ..... };
```

If we want to know if a tile happens to be safe to move into (no wall) we could do this:

```
    if( level1_map[y][x] & IS_WALL == 0) {
```

For the opposite, if we want to know if a tile is a wall we could do any of these:

```
    if( level1_map[y][x] & IS_WALL != 0) {

    if( !level1_map[y][x] & IS_WALL == 0) {

    if( level1_map[y][x] & IS_WALL == IS_WALL) {
```

..because it makes no difference which one it is.

Of course (to avoid the risk of typos) GCC might (or might not) warn about some of these.

Comment: Assume `level1_map[y][x] == 0x2`, then `(!level1_map[y][x]) == 0` then  `((!level1_map[y][x]) & IS_WALL) == 0` so I don't think that second case is a correct way to test for a wall.

Comment: If your dog barks, take a look outside, it could be just a cat, or it could be a thief. If your compiler barks, it's the same, always take a look at your source code. I prefer a pedantic compiler. The problem with legacy code is that it sees a laot of cats and barks a lot.

Comment: @aka.nice: Ah - you're right - it should be `if( ~level1_map[y][x] & IS_WALL == 0) {`.